# How to access node fields in template_preprocess_node(Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7

I want to access a node field in template_preprocess_node.My site is multilingual and the form of the field in node array is something like

$node->field_my_field['en'][0]['value'].

Is there another way to access the value of this field?Because with this way I should specify the user language.(I want just field value not the value with it's label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [field_get_items](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function.

This is the best way to get field items, don't reference them directly with a fixed language.